# Add an object to a var div element

Tags: javascript

So I am creating a "GoogleMap component" within a Single Page Application.

I have been given some patterns to follow that are inspired by an AS2 expert. He wants to have instances of GoogleMaps available to the SPA. Some of the goals of the pattern are, of course, encapsulation and reusability.

The pattern goes as follows:

```
GoogleMap = { instances: [] }; //static instance,wrapper class

GoogleMap.get = function () {
    var mapCanvas = document.createElement('div');

    if (this.instances.length > 0) {
        return this.instances.pop();
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions); //mapOptions are defined don't worry
     return mapCanvas;
}


GoogleMap.destroy = function (googleMap) {
    this.instances.push(googleMap);
}
```

Then in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        var mapDiv = GoogleMap.get();
        document.body.appendChild(mapDiv);
        //here lies my issue
        //mapDiv.setMapCenter({ lat: 90, long: 90 });
    }
    window.onload = start;
</script>
```

I want to be able to add an object to mapDiv which is only a html element right now.
I thought all vars in Javascript inherit from Object except null and undefined. So I thought I could do, in `GoogleMap.get`:

```
var mapCanvas = document.createElement('div');
mapCanvas.prototype.setMapCenter = function(lat,long){ //error no prototype!

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
            this.instance.setCenter(location);

    return mapCanvas, which has a method that the caller can use to set lat and long, awesome! If only it worked the way my mind it thinking it would
}
```

But there is no prototype for the var mapCanvas which is just a `<div>`

Comment: The usual way around this is to create your own wrapper object that has the `mapDiv` in its instance data.  You return the wrapper object instead of the `mapDiv` and you can then add as many custom methods as you want to the wrapper object since it's your own custom object.

Comment: Have you seen this pattern before of managing instances in this way?

Comment: It is what jQuery (probably the most popular browser javascript framework) does.